# Difficulty using #[ink::trait_definition] with non-'static associated type Env

Tags: ink

I noticed that in the following code snippet, the `Env` associated type is not constrained to be `'static`:

```rust
pub trait ContractEnv {
    /// The environment type.
    type Env: crate::Environment;
}
```

I'm wondering why this is the case. If `Env` were `'static`, it would be possible to use it more easily in standalone `#[ink::trait_definition]` implementations, like so:

```rust
#[ink::trait_definition]
pub trait IAccount {
    #[ink(message)]
    fn validate_user_op(
        &self,
        user_op: UserOperation<Self::Env>,
        user_op_hash: Hash<Self::Env>,
        missing_account_funds: Balance<Self::Env>,
    ) -> ValidationData<Self::Env>;
}
type Hash<E> = <E as Environment>::Hash;
type Balance<E> = <E as Environment>::Balance;

#[derive(scale::Encode, scale::Decode, Clone, Hash, Debug)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub struct UserOperation<E: Environment> {
    pub sender: E::AccountId,
    pub nonce: u64,
    pub init_code: Vec<u8>,
    pub call_data: Vec<u8>,
    pub call_gas_limit: E::Balance,
    pub verification_gas_limit: E::Balance,
    pub pre_verification_gas: E::Balance,
    pub max_fee_per_gas: E::Balance,
    pub max_priority_fee_per_gas: E::Balance,
}
```

I'm aware that there are workarounds for this issue, but they can be quite cumbersome. Is there a specific reason why `'static` was not added as a constraint for the `Env` associated type?

Thank you for your time.